# Swift : Use of unresolved identifier 'json'

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm currently developing my first iOS app using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.0.1.

I'm getting a strange little error that I can't seem to fix:

```
        var err: NSError?
```

The original code:

```
        //var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
```

Swift2 rewrite code:

```
        do {
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print(json)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Use of unresolved identifier 'json' before rewriting

```
        if let parseJSON = json {
            var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
            print("result: \(resultValue)")

            var isUserRegistered:Bool = false;
            if(resultValue=="Success") { isUserRegistered = true; }

            var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
            if(!isUserRegistered)
            {
                messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                //Display alert message with confirmation.
                var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
                }

                myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
            });  
        }
```

The error is thrown at this line:

```
            if let parseJSON = json {
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: move your code to the if let statement...

Comment: your json not declared globally...so you need to move your code from `if let parseJSON = json` into do...catch

Comment: Such messages appear after rewriting this normal? [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9oZrweCVU4jdUk4UXdBM0lLaDg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: just follow the instruction and you can sort out that messages

Comment: OK! There is no mistake, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable `json` is visible only in the scope of the `do` block.

Move the code into the `do` block.
Optional bindings is not needed, too. If the code passes the `try` statement, `parseJSON` is valid and non-optional.

```
do {
   let parseJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary {
   print(parseJSON)
   var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
   print("result: \(resultValue)")

   var isUserRegistered:Bool = false;
   if(resultValue=="Success") { isUserRegistered = true; }

   var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
   if(!isUserRegistered)
   {
      messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
   }

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

      //Display alert message with confirmation.
      var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

      let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in
          self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
       }

       myAlert.addAction(okAction);
       self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
   });  

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Such messages appear after rewriting this normal? [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9oZrweCVU4jdUk4UXdBM0lLaDg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The migration from Swift 1 to 2 is a huge step. Even using the automatic migrator a lot of errors and warnings could be displayed. For some of them the compiler suggests solutions. For the others read the error listing and resolve the problems manually. A good way is to command-click on the affected symbol to read the signature and compare it with the current syntax.