# Use of unresolved identifier 'json'

Tags: json, swift

I am receiving the error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'json'`

from this line:  `if let parseJSON = json {`

This is the snippet of the code relevant to the error

```
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
          data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                    print(jsonResult)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            if let parseJSON = json {
                var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as String!;
                print("Result: \(resultValue)")

                if(resultValue=="Success")
                {

            //Login is sucessful
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
             NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

}

}

task.resume()

}

}
```

I reviewed this problem: [Swift : Use of unresolved identifier 'json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253340/swift-use-of-unresolved-identifier-json) but I do not know how I can fix my issue or where to put the variable of `json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to write `if let parseJSON = jsonResult` but anyways that is not gonna work either since the variables declared in the `do` are only visible at that scope. you need to move relevant code inside the `do`. You can assign the result of JSONSerialization directly to `parsJSON`.

You should also change this line `var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as String!` to `var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String`

Modify your code like this:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
    do {
        if let parseJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            print(parseJSON)

            let resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String
            print("Result: \(resultValue)")

            if(resultValue=="Success")
            {
                //Login is sucessful
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
task.resume()

}

}
```

Comment: I received 5 issues

Comment: @PHPWebDev101 I tested the code, there were no errors. Can you please tell me what errors are you receiving?

Comment: No, I did not update my post. I did not show the entire code though (just a snippet I thought was relevant), would it be helpful if I did? Here are the errors I encountered - http://imgur.com/a/lgiEn

Comment: Did you include `task.resume()` and the two curly brackets at the end? I thought it was clear that those should be there. let me edit my answer.

Comment: Could you do the same to one more script please?